# Is there any way to save and read multi-dimension data with efficiency?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, multiple-columns

#### Introduction

- I have a bunch of data series with 1000 stations and each station all have 4 features (e.g Temperature, Wind, CO2 concentration, solar radiation).
- All the features are in time-series with hourly resolution.

I read this data in **.csv** files with the support of Pandas.

Now I need to save and organize them together for better re-use.

#### My solution

I creat columns entitled by 'sample_x, feature_y'. And each column contain the time series data of feature_y for sample_x.

This method is doable but not show efficiency. Because I had to creat like 4000 columns  with long column name.

#### My question

Is there any better way to save multi-demensions data in Python. I want a simple solution that can help me assessing and handling with specific data directly.

Any advices or solution is appreciated!

Comment: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/ is designed precisely to handle storage and manipulation of weather data ; it is built on top of pandas

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) or [`Panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel) and then if necessary save data to [`hdf5`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5).

Also function [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) have parameter `keys` which create `MultiIndex` from `list of DataFrames`.

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5]})

print (df1)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  7  1
1  2  5  8  3
2  3  6  9  5

df2 = df1 * 10

dfs = [df1, df2]

df3 = pd.concat(dfs, keys=['a','b'])
print (df3)
      A   B   C   D
a 0   1   4   7   1
  1   2   5   8   3
  2   3   6   9   5
b 0  10  40  70  10
  1  20  50  80  30
  2  30  60  90  50

print (df3.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b'], [0, 1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

---

```
wp = pd.Panel({'a' : df1, 'b' : df2})
print (wp)
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 3 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: a to b
Major_axis axis: 0 to 2
Minor_axis axis: A to D
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [HDF](http://www.h5py.org/), which has been specifically designed to handle huge arrays of multidimensional data.

Comment: I have learned to use the HDF files. And it works pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer may be just to create a [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#module-sqlite3) database.

It sounds like you have 6 pieces of data per hour (station, timestamp, feature1..feature4) times 1000 stations, times however-many hours.

So that's 6000 data items (at, say, 4 bytes each = 24k), times 24 hours/day times 365 days/year (* 8760), or about 200mb, per year. Depending on how far back you're going, that's not too bad for a db file. (If you're going to do more than 10 years, then yeah, go to something bigger, or maybe compress the data or break it up by year or something...)