# Pandas: is there a way to work with multi-value cells?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with room for multivalued cells. E.g. a customer having arbitrary number of emails. Or a book having multple authors. And it's still a single row.

What are Pandas way to handle data with such nature? It there a way to store and efficiently work with multivalued data?

Comment: I think you need `MultiIndex` or `Panel`

Comment: maybe help this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42641335/2901002)